# Шаблонизатор blade в laravel

Tags: laravel

Хочу создать в Laravel что-то вроде такой структуры:

1. Главный файл шаблона: views/index.blade.php, содержащий внутри себя разделы `head` (мета-теги), `content` и разделы для вывода модулей (виджетов) (например, `@yield('content')`.
2. Файлы шаблонов для каждой из страниц: views/pages/..., где каждая из страниц описывает указанные в "index.blade.php" секции.
3. Файлы виджетов: views/widgets/..., где описываются разметки всех виджетов.

Как это реализуется на Laravel? Например, контроллер выводит отображение для конкретной страницы следующим образом:

```
return view('index');
```

Таким образом, у меня выведется общий файл шаблона "index.blade.php". Каким образом сделать так, чтобы, например, общий файл шаблона выводился на каждой странице, а текст внутри областей `head` и `content` генерировался файлами внутри папки "pages"?

И второй вопрос: правильно ли в данном случае подключать виджеты (модули) при помощи директивы `@include` внутри файла конкретной страницы (views/pages)? Что-то вроде этого:

```
@section('widgets')
    @include('widgets.miniprofile')
@stop
```

Сам раздел `widgets` при этом был бы описан внутри основного "index.blade.php" (yield).

Answer (score 1):

По поводу глобального шаблона, используйте @extend
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#extending-a-layout

Сделайте из вашего index.blade.php мастер-файл и остальными просто расширяйте его.
Т.е. каждый новый файл в "pages" будет состоять из блоков

```
@section('head')
...
@endsection
@section('content')
...
@endsection
```

Всё остальное будет описано в основном мастер-файле.

Вообще в приведенной выше документации всё хорошо расписано, также в laravel 5.2 можно сделать artisan make:auth, эта команда сгенерит шаблон авторизации и главной страницы, можно посмотреть как сделана структура вьюх там.

По поводу инклуда виджетов, да, в целом всё верно.
Можно их инклудить внутрь вьюх из "pages", если они разные для всех страниц, а можно сразу внутрь основного мастер-файла.

Comment: `@endsection` - deprecated, поменяйте на `@stop` http://stackoverflow.com/a/21199876/4581725

Answer (score 1):

Я еще только начинаю разбираться, но сделал бы это как-то так: 
добавил в контроллер массив `$data`. Наполнил его нужными данными. В ключе 'widgets' добавляем на ключ частицы данные которые надо передать в макет.

Например: `$data['widgets']['menu'] = []`

В макете по проверяем ключ, если передан выводим или через `@foreach` пробегаемся по переменной данным из widgets и инклудим соответствующую часть шаблона по имени ключа, передавая в неё данные этого массива.

Я думаю это самая оптимальная реализация, буду пробовать. Сам сейчас задался вопросом, и сам же себе ответил.

Сейчас использую такую структуру шаблона:

```
views/templates/<template-name>.blade.php
views/layouts/<layout-name>.blade.php
views/particles/<widgets>/<name>.blade.php
```

из контроллера вызываем нужный макет, а уже в макете расширяется шаблон, и там же выше указанный способ вызова виджетов.

Comment: Еще нашел вот такую статью, если функционал не выпелен, то можно в контроллере собирать данные для вьюх, и тоже просто инклудить их в макете https://habrahabr.ru/post/222453/ п.6